# Why is Linq2EF Join Generating a full outer join?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, odp.net

I'm using some simple LINQ in my EF 4.3.1:

```
Dim Results = (
    From T1 In Context.Table1
    Where T1.IDColumn = 1568
    Join T2 In Context.Table2 On T1.IDColumn Equals T2.IDColumn
    Select New With {
        .Quantity = T1.Quantity
    })
```

Unfortunately when I run this it's takeing forever.  And I've tracked the problem down to what appears to be a completely unneccessary portion of the generated SQL.  The generated SQL looks like this:

```
SELECT   1 AS "C1"
        ,CAST( "Extent2"."Quantity" AS number(19,0)) AS "C2"  
FROM  [table1] "Extent1"  
INNER JOIN [table2] "Extent2" ON 
(
  ( 
    CAST( "Extent1"."IDColumn" AS number(19,0))
  ) = (
    CAST( "Extent2"."IDColumn" AS number(19,0))
  )
) 
OR 
(
  ( 
    CAST( "Extent1"."IDColumn" AS number(19,0)) IS NULL
  ) 
  AND 
  ( 
    CAST( "Extent2"."IDColumn" AS number(19,0)) IS NULL
  )
)  
WHERE 
(
  1568 = ( 
    CAST( "Extent1"."ForeginKey" AS number(19,0))
  )
)
```

This query takes about 13 seconds to execute.  If I remove the OR / NULL block, it goes down to 0.122 seconds:

```
    SELECT   1 AS "C1"
            ,CAST( "Extent2"."Quantity" AS number(19,0)) AS "C2"  
    FROM  [table1] "Extent1"  
    INNER JOIN [table2] "Extent2" ON 
    (
      ( 
        CAST( "Extent1"."IDColumn" AS number(19,0))
      ) = (
        CAST( "Extent2"."IDColumn" AS number(19,0))
      )
    ) 
    WHERE 
    (
      1568 = ( 
        CAST( "Extent1"."ForeginKey" AS number(19,0))
      )
    )
```

Anyone have suggestions for how I can get the linq query to not generate the (undesired) null checks?

Comment: What is the type of `IDColumn` in your .NET model and in the database?

Comment: In the database, field type is Number(10,0), in .NET I have it mapped to Int64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the data type of the column being compared from Int64 to Decimal, per Microsoft's [Data Type map](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yk72thhd%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), and the query and performance improved dramatically.  Thanks to Jon Skeet for getting me on the right path.